# Rate of change of radius and volume

Tags: calculus

They  put a gas bubble in someone's eye. The volume of a gas bubble changes from $0.4$ $cc$ to $1.6$ $cc$ in $74$ hours. Assuming that the rate of change of the radius is constant, find

- (a) The rate at which the radius changes;
- (b) The rate at which the volume of the bubble is increasing at any volume $V$;
- (c) The rate at which the volume is increasing when the volume

is $1$ $cc$.
(Note: The volume of a ball of radius $r$ is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$. Assume
the bubble is spherical.)

Explanation would be appreciated.

I did differentiate the $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ with respect to r that is $4\pi r^2$ and then made that equal to $1.66-06$ which is the rate change of $V$. But I Don't know if I am doing it right.

Comment: Remember that if the radius grows by a factor of x then the volume grows by X^3. So if the volume grew 4 times then the radius grew by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$

or

$r=(3v/4\pi)^{1/3}$

$\frac{dv}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}$
substitute for $r$ we get

and letting $dr/dt=K$ (constant) then

$v^{-2/3}dv=4\pi K(3/(4\pi))^{2/3} dt$

$3v^{1/3} = 4\pi K(3/(4\pi))^{2/3} dt$

Integrating between limits $0.4$ and $1.6$ for V and $t=0$ to $74$, we get
$K= \frac{1.6^{1/3}-.4^{1/3}}{74 (4\pi/3)^{1/3}}$
which works out to $3.628E-3 cm/hr$ as the rate of change of radius.

b)  $dv/dt=(36\pi)^{1/3} KV^{2/3}$

c) substitute $v=1$ in above we get $(36\pi)^{1/3} K$

Comment: It would be alot easier for part 1 to just: $$K = \frac{\sqrt[3]{1.6*3/4/\pi}-\sqrt[3]{0.4*3/4/\pi}}{74} cm/hr$$ but they both get the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  what are the starting and ending radii?  Let $t$ be the number of hours from the start.  Now write an equation $r=$ some function of $t$.  Use that to write another equation $V=$ some function of $t$  Now use these functions to answer the questions.

Answer (score 0):

If the radius increases at a constant rate, $r = \alpha t+r_o$ for some constant $\alpha$.

this simplifies the questions to:

a) What are the values of $\alpha$ and $r_o$? (should be solvable from the data)

b) Write $V(t)$, solve for $\frac{dV}{dt}$, and write that in terms of just V.

c) Specifically plug $V=1 cc$ into the answer for b.

Note that we are hesitating to give a direct answer as this appears to be homework but I will gladly confirm any answers you come up with.